# when vector<int> in unordered_map<int,vector<int>>.i cant change vector size,why?

Tags: c++

```
unordered_map<int, vector<int>> map1;
vector<int> node_sum;
node_sum.push_back(10);
map1.insert(pair<int, vector<int>>(0, node_sum));
node_sum = map1.at(0);
node_sum.push_back(1);
node_sum.push_back(2);
cout <<"map1.at(0).size():"<< map1.at(0).size() << endl;
cout << "node_sum.size():" << node_sum.size()<< endl;
```

there will output:

map1.at(0).size():1
node_sum.size():3

why i cant change vector size

Comment: The map holds a *copy* of the vector. Modifying the original after copying it obviously doesn't affect the copy

Comment: `node_sum = map1.at(0);` <- node_sum is a vector, and the vector is a vector, and they are not the same vector

Comment: `vector<int>& node_sum = map1[0];` https://godbolt.org/z/E3xhsMhMz

Comment: Why do you want to write `map1.insert(pair<int, vector<int>>(0, node_sum));` when you can write `map1[0] = node_sum;`?

Answer (score 2):

After `map1.insert(pair<int, vector<int>>(0, node_sum))`, the map holds a *copy* of node_sum. `node_sum` and the object in the map are independent objects of the same type. You can see this by putting node_sum into a small scope and getting a reference to the object in the map. If you implement a test object with copy constructor, destructor etc that prints a message you can see what is going on in detail.

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() {cout << "Foo::Foo" << endl;}
    ~Foo() {cout << "Foo::~Foo" << endl;}
    Foo(Foo const& f) {cout << "Foo::Foo(const&)" << endl;}
    Foo& operator(Foo const& f) {cout << "operator=" << endl; return *this;}
};

int main() {
    {
        unordered_map<int, Foo> map1;
        {
            Foo foo;      
            map1.insert(make_pair(0, foo));
        }
        cout << "Will delete map1" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`node_sum = map1.at(0);` probably does not what you think it should do. It returns a reference to the object in the map and then calls the assignment operator of `std::vector` on `node_sum` with the returned reference as parameter. This will copy the content of the object in the map into `node_sum`, but you still have two separate objects. Try

```
auto& map_node_sum = map1.at(0);
map_node_sum .push_back(1);
map_node_sum .push_back(2);
cout <<"map1.at(0).size():"<< map1.at(0).size() << endl;
cout << "map_node_sum .size():" << map_node_sum .size()<< endl;
cout << "node_sum.size():" << node_sum.size()<< endl;
```

You could also use return value of `map::insert` directly to save a query.

Comment: Thanks, I see. unordered_map in c++ uses a deep copy

Comment: @zaizilong For elements of type `std::vector` this is true, but the semantics depend on the copy constructor and assigment operators of the value type. When inserting, the copy constructor (or move constructor) is called. In your original code, `auto& node_sum = map1.at(0)` calls the assignment operator.